# clear table jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have an **HTML table** filled with a number of rows.

How can I **remove** all the rows from the table?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Use **[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)**

```
$("#yourtableid tr").remove();
```

If you want to keep the data for future use even after removing it then you can use **[.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)**

```
$("#yourtableid tr").detach();
```

If the rows are children of the table then you can use child selector instead of descendant selector, like

```
$("#yourtableid > tr").remove();
```

Comment: careful with that last one: most browsers add an implicit `tbody` element around the `tr` elements.

Answer (score 119):

If you want to clear the data but keep the headers:

```
$('#myTableId tbody').empty();
```

The table must be formatted in this manner:

```
<table id="myTableId">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header1</th><th>header2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td><td>data2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this is working, but this removing the 'tbody' itself with all the 'tr' inside it.

Comment: You're right, @HakamFostok. I've edited my answer to use empty() instead

Answer (score 44):

Slightly quicker than removing each one individually:

```
$('#myTable').empty()
```

Technically, this will remove `thead`, `tfoot` and `tbody` elements too.

Answer (score 29):

I needed this:

```
$('#myTable tbody > tr').remove();
```

It deletes all rows except the header.

Answer (score 14):

```
$("#employeeTable td").parent().remove();
```

This will remove all `tr` having  `td` as child. i.e all rows except the header will be deleted.

Comment: This is the only one that works for me. Delete all except the header...

Answer (score 12):

The nuclear option:

```
$("#yourtableid").html("");
```

Destroys everything inside of `#yourtableid`.  Be careful with your selectors, as it will destroy *any* html in the selector you pass!

Comment: +1 for nuclear :). But should understand that is not the 'best' style :) I would not recommend it in general

Comment: lol.  Agreed. I have used this particular method in the past for speed and *resolving difficult situations*.  It has some valid use in the realm of JQuery applications.

Answer (score 10):

This will remove all of the rows belonging to the body, thus keeping the headers and body intact:

```
$("#tableLoanInfos tbody tr").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<table id="myTable" class="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tblBody">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

And Remove:

```
$("#tblBody").empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#myTable > tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a table like this (with a header and a body)

```
<table id="myTableId">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

remove every tr having a parent called tbody inside the #tableId

```
$('#tableId tbody > tr').remove();
```

and in reverse if you want to add to your table

```
$('#tableId tbody').append("<tr><td></td>....</tr>");
```