# How to refresh tag in javascript using google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How can i refresh my table tag without reloading my page? In my current code, it refreshing but i notice that its like refreshing the whole document. I am trying to make a filter function where it filter the date only. So when i check 1 radio button and then fetch it, the radio button i checked will refresh also(became unchecked). So how i can refresh my table only? Help me with this please. I am doing this project since January 2018.

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();

}

function getData() {
   return JSON.stringify(SpreadsheetApp.openById('17lKIhONfEeNogsBhKtGr4zVaLgH0_199-3J3-0tAdcE')
  .getActiveSheet()
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues());
}

function include(JavaScript) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(JavaScript)
      .getContent();
}

function setApproved(a, b) {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().getContent();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('17lKIhONfEeNogsBhKtGr4zVaLgH0_199-3J3-0tAdcE');
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();

  var headers = values[0];
  var ldapIndex = headers.indexOf('dbName');
  var idIndex = headers.indexOf('dbID');
  var statusIndex = headers.indexOf('dbStatus');
  var sheetRow;

  for( var i = 1 ; i < values.length; i++ ) {
    var row = values[i];
    if(row[idIndex] == a && row[ldapIndex] == b) { 
      sheetRow = i +1;
      break;
    }
  }

  ++statusIndex;
  sheet.getRange(sheetRow, statusIndex).setValue('Approved');

  return html;
}
function fetchData() {
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().getContent();
return html;
}
```

**Index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">

      </head>

      <body>
      <? var data = getData(); ?>
      <div id="Options">
        <label><b>Month</b></label>
        <select id="selectMonth">
          <option value="0">-Select Month-</option>
          <option value="1">January</option>       
          <option value="2">February</option>       
          <option value="3">March</option>       
          <option value="4">April</option>       
          <option value="5">May</option>       
          <option value="6">June</option>       
          <option value="7">July</option>       
          <option value="8">August</option>       
          <option value="9">September</option>       
          <option value="10">October</option>       
          <option value="11">November</option>       
          <option value="12">December</option>
        </select> - 
      <input type="radio" name="radioYear" id="radioYear" value="<?= new Date().getYear(); ?>"> <?= new Date().getYear(); ?>
      <input type="radio" name="radioYear" id="radioYear2" value="<?= new Date().getYear()+1; ?>"> <?= new Date().getYear()+1; ?>
      <button id="btnFetch" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fetchRecord).getData()">Fetch</button>
      </div>
      <div  id="tables">
            <table id="tableShift2">
            <caption>Team unknown</caption>
              <th>   Date and Time Plotted   </th>
              <th>   Name   </th>
              <th>   Date of VL   </th>
              <th>   HD/WD   </th>
              <th>   Action   </th>
            </table>
      </div>
      <div id="date"></div>
    <script
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData)
      .getData();
});

function showData(things1) {
  var things = JSON.parse(things1);
  var table = $('#tableShift2');

    for (var i = 1; i < things.length; i++) {
      var monthNames = [
        "January", "February", "March",
        "April", "May", "June", "July",
        "August", "September", "October", 
        "November", "December"
      ];

      var date = new Date(things[i][1]);
      var day = date.getDate();
      var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      var hour = date.getHours();
      var minute = date.getMinutes();
      var second = date.getSeconds();

      if (things[i][6] == '') {
        table.append('<tr> <td>' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + day + ', ' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second +
                 '</td> <td>' + things[i][2] +
                 '</td> <td>' + things[i][3] +
                 '</td> <td>' + things[i][4] +
                 '</td> <td ><button onclick=\'ApproveAndRefresh("' + things[i][0] + '","' + things[i][2] +
                 '")\' id="btnApprove">Approve</button> <button onclick=\'DeclineAndRefresh("' + things[i][0] + '","' + things[i][2] + 
                 '")\' id="btnDecline">Decline</button></td></tr>');

      }

  }
}
function ApproveAndRefresh(data, data1){
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(refreshData)
  .setApproved(data, data1);
}

function DeclineAndRefresh(data, data1){
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(refreshData)
  .setDeclined(data, data1);
}

function refreshData(hl){
   document.open();
   document.write(hl);
   document.close();
}

</script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is (kind of) a big question. It requires some refactoring of your current code (to make it look/work nicely). If you want to just make it work you need to use `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().callFunc()` to get data from the server then update your HTML code with the data returned. Right now in your code `setApproved()` and `setDeclined()` both call HTMLService and reload your page. Instead, you want to return data back to the page and update the HTML using javascript. Read this [Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a `showData()` function that refreshes the data but doesn't refresh the page. You can use that to update your table. Currently, you have it setup to append row to your table `table.append()`. However, you will need to clear the table first without removing your headers as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620181/clear-table-jquery).So the function would be modified like so:

```
function showData(things1) {
  var things = JSON.parse(things1);
  $('#tableShift2 tbody').remove(); //Remove Previous table, except headers
  var table = $('#tableShift2');
  ... //Remaining code remains the same
}
```

Or you can create the headers also programmatically, with `table.append()` 
Next, you will need to modify the `ApproveAndRefresh()` and `DeclineAndRefresh()` functions so that `showData()` function is called on Success, like so:

```
function ApproveAndRefresh(data, data1){
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(showData)
  .setApproved(data, data1);
}
```

Finally, the `setApproved` and `setDecline()` currently return HTML content. However, they only need to return the `getData()` values like so:

```
function setApproved(a, b) {
  // You dont need the recreate the page 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('17lKIhONfEeNogsBhKtGr4zVaLgH0_199-3J3-0tAdcE');
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  ... // The rest of the code remains same here
  ++statusIndex;
  sheet.getRange(sheetRow, statusIndex).setValue('Approved');

  return getData()  //You just return values generated from getData()
}
```

Equivalently, you can just return spreadsheet data like so

```
 return JSON.stringfy(ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues())
```